# Docpad: generate php output file

Tags: docpad

I'm using Docpad to generate static files for a standard, LAMP-hosted site. I want to implement password access one of the pages, so my intention was to use a php page with [this](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/password-protect.php) password_protect script.

I've setup my docpad 'layout' to add `<?php include...` to the relevant page, and use `.php` as the suffix on the particular document, but the output I'm getting is `.html`.

My reading of the docs is that Docpad considers php as a pre-processor, not as an output type, so is there anything I can easily do to save myself hand-renaming the file when I deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's kind of strange.  I thought the extension after the basename would be the output extension.  This fixed it for me.  Put it under events in your [docpad config file](https://docpad.org/docs/config) or as a method in a [plugin](https://docpad.org/docs/plugin-write).

```
  writeBefore: (opts) ->
    {collection, templateData} = opts
    collection.forEach (file,index) ->
      ext = file.get('extensions')[0]
      if ext == 'php'
        outDirPath = file.get('outDirPath') 
        basename = file.get('basename')
        outFilename = basename + '.php'
        file.set('outPath', outDirPath + '/' + outFilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DocPad layouts? It seems (at least now) that layout extensions take priority over resource extensions. Maybe using a layout with php extension will solve the problem.

## How to use one layout for multiple extensions

If you don't want to duplicate a layout file (which defeats the purpose of layouts), you could create a symbolic link to the parent layout, like so (on linux in the `layout` folder):

```
ln -s layoutname.html.eco php-layoutname.php.eco
```

Don't forget to update the `layout` property in the frontmatter of your php files afterwards!

Comment: This is more of a question or request for clarification, which should be handled in comments below the question. The *answer* section is maintained only for viable technical solutions to understood problems.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14756774)

Comment: @hotapplecyber You're right there is some guessing involved. (How) should I move it? Also I'm not entirely sure I'm already allowed to comment on OP.

Comment: This is not a question because it helped solve the extension problem in my case (hence I posted it here :)).

Comment: Don't worry about it. Not too bad in this case, just keep it in mind for next time. Overall,  a decent response. Hang in there. Participate. Your reputation pts will grow and you'll get more abilities/access here, such as being able to comment - which you can earn pretty fast.  This brilliant community run site, has many cool incentives, great tools and reasons to participate. I encourage you to look at the "review" link at top and see how people participate and help here, it's how/why I found/responded to your post. Also look into the badges and hats, and the different kinds of access.

Comment: [review link at top](http://stackoverflow.com/review), also [about badges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) You can even earn a badge by reading the [documentation tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation)